# How can i restrict login & call to database each time on startup in .net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm using .net core, and using identity server to login and signup. once sign in done successfully next time it should not go to database call and check that provided password are valid or not on all time on startup time.

Comment: do you mean the part with peristing cookies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1#peristentcokies

Comment: No dear, that a totally different things because it's not using identity, it's using database identity.

Comment: I still couldn't understand your requirement clearly. As far as I now if we has login successfully, the identity server will return a token. We could use that token to access Identity server protected resources. If the token is expire or else, we need to go to identity server to ask another token.

Comment: I means i'm using SQL to identity login and signup. Now i using middle ware which do round trip to database on first time when client come to my site. I want to login that directly from somewhere like not call to database all time to login.